# Find Regex Group of <colgroup>

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a below group of elements and I want to find the `<colgroup>` of Groups.

```
<colgroup>
  <col width="2184"></col>
  <col width="3743">
  <col width="3743">
</colgroup>
<colgroup>
  <col width="2184">
  <col widcth="3743">
  <col width="3743">
</colgroup>
<colgroup>
  <col width="2184">
  <col width="3743">
  <col width="3743">
</colgroup>
```

I want three group of `<colgroup></colgroup>` and I tried the below thing which is not working

right.

```
  /<colgroup>(.*?)<\/colgroup>/g
```

Comment: You need to use `DOMDocument` instead of doing it in wrong way, like you do right now

Comment: Why not use an XMLParser?

Comment: No I'm dealing with String

Comment: Try `(.*?|\n)*?` or use /s flag to make the dot match a new line

Comment: Can you please Give an regex Fiddle Example for this?I'm really new to regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 /<colgroup>(.*?)<\/colgroup>/g
```

Here the `.` will match everything except a new line.
In this,

```
(.*?|\n)*?
```

If you add `(.*?|\n)*?` it will also match the new line between `<colgroup>` and `</colgroup>`

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/Dr7ly2/14)

Comment: Your double `*?` is not that good performance wise it would be better to use `(.|\n)*?` . So only use the quantifier once.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have experienced stack overflow error in `(.|\n)*?` while parsing huge strings. So I suggested this.

Comment: Though it wasn't exactly what I was looking form it helped me solve my problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<colgroup>[^]+?<\/colgroup>` to match everything including new lines.

Here is the [**Regex**](https://regex101.com/r/LwfHm1/1)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use the `gsm` flags as an alternative to match the three groups including the new line characters. This seems to work in the latest version of Chrome as of Sept 2018. But this does not work on Firefox (Sept 2018).

`m` is multiline flag

`s` is the dot matches all flag

It seems that there is a proposal to include this feature in future versions of Javascript: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/07/upcoming-regexp-features

Here is a running example which runs on Chrome:

```js
let targetText = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
var reg = /<colgroup>(.+?)<\/colgroup>/gsm;
var result;
while((result = reg.exec(targetText)) !== null) {
    console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<table id="test">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="2184" />
    <col width="3743" />
    <col width="3743" />
  </colgroup>
  <colgroup>
    <col width="2184" />
    <col widcth="3743" />
    <col width="3743" />
  </colgroup>
  <colgroup>
    <col width="2184" />
    <col width="3743" />
    <col width="3743" />
  </colgroup>
</table>
```